# isset($_POST['submit']) not working now

Tags: php, mysql

This was working, but right now when I got back to this, it stopped working.
I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Please help.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        require("dbconn.php");
        $filename = $_POST['filename'];
        $name = $filename . pathinfo($_FILES['ufile']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //$name = $_FILES['ufile']['name'];
        echo $name;
        //$size = $_FILES['file']['size']
        //$type = $_FILES['file']['type']

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'];
        $error = $_FILES['ufile']['error'];

        if (isset ($name)) 
        {
            if (!empty($name)) 
            {
                $location = 'uploads/';

                if  (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
                {
                    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
                    $filepath = $location.$name;
                    $advname = $_POST['advname'];
                    $year = $_POST['year'];
                    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
                    $ctype = $_POST['ctype'];
                    $sqlq = "INSERT INTO file (filename, filepath, advname, year, cname, ctype) VALUES ('".$filename."','".$filepath."','".$advname."','".$year."','".$cname."','".$ctype."');";
                    $result = mysql_query($sqlq);
                    if(!$result)
                    {
                        die("Error in connecting to database!");
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
?>

<form id="form1" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>File Name</label>
            <input id="filename" name="filename" type="text" value=""/><br>

            <label>Advocate Name</label>
            <select name = "advname">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Adv 1">Adv 1</option>
                <option value="Adv 2">Adv 2</option>
                <option value="Adv 3">Adv 3</option>
            </select><br>

            <label>Year<label>
            <input id="year" name="year" type="date"><br>

            <label>Company Name</label>
            <input id="cname" name = "cname" type="text"><br>

            <label>Court Type</label>
            <input id="ctype" type="text" name = "ctype"><br>

            <label>Scan</label>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="scanSimple();">Simple Scan</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="scan();">Scan</button><br>

            <label>Upload</label>
            <input type="file" name="ufile" id="ufile"><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm1();">
        </form>
```

Both these code are a part of the same file. 
Please let me know of where I could be going wrong, because I can't seem to find any mistake.

I've tried echoing inside the if statement and it doesn't display anything.

Comment: your `isset` looks fine but there could be other errors inside `if statement` which are causing a blank page `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` do this to check for errors and share your `onclick="submitForm1();` code

Comment: Can you please add you js code that calling following function. onclick="submitForm1();"

Comment: try to check echo var_dump($_POST)

Comment: @yiiframe It is not causing me a blank page. If i echo out anything outside that page, it works. And it didn't show me any errors.

Comment: @AyyanarG That just gave me an empty array.

Comment: I even tried removing the onClick option from there, but still same result.

Comment: remove onClick and add `form action` to your file name and then submit the page if it works

Comment: Everything seems to be fine but I just noticed few things. Can you please add id="submit" and remove onclick attribute from your input button and add name="form1" attribute to form tag then try ..

Comment: @yiiframe Didn't work. Same.

Comment: What server are you using?? xamp, wamp

Comment: you need to share Javascript code where `submitForm1` is defined

Comment: @Iffi LAMP is what I'm using

Comment: Yup! I have tested on my side in LAMP Its working perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing action="current file name" in first line of form tag...

```
   <form id="form1" method="POST" action="current file name/example.php"     enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

OR use this.

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"     enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: `form` without `action` attribute will be submitted to same file, which the OP intends to do here.

Answer (score 0):

In my php.ini file I had set the the `post_max_size` less than the `upload_max_filesize` and that was creating this problem.